# TomEE and MySql - query don't returns any results

Tags: mysql, entitymanager, apache-tomee

I am using TomeEE + MySql and i have problem because function createNamedQuery don't returns any results. I thought that problem is with my
entityManager but i checked in debugMode and is injected.

This is my code:

User Entity:

```
package pl.gsite.db.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.loginAndPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.login = :login and u.password = :password"),    
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findById", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByLogin", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.login = :login"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.password = :password")})
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof User)) {
            return false;
        }
        User other = (User) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "pl.gsite.db.model.User[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

My ManagedBean:

```
package pl.gsite.bean.request;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.enterprise.context.spi.Context;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import pl.gsite.bean.session.LoggedUserBean;
import pl.gsite.db.model.User;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
import javax.persistence.Query;



@Named(value = "loginRequest")
@RequestScoped
public class LoginRequest {
   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "gsitePU")
   private EntityManager em;

   @Inject
   private LoggedUserBean loggedUserBean;
   private String login;
   private String password;

    public LoginRequest() {
    }

    public String authentication() {        
        try {
            List<User> uList = new ArrayList<User>();            
            TypedQuery qq = em.createNamedQuery("User.findAll", User.class);
            uList = qq.getResultList(); // <-- returns empty list
            TypedQuery<User> query = em.createNamedQuery("User.loginAndPassword", User.class).setParameter("login", login).setParameter("password", password);    
            User u = query.getSingleResult(); // <-- throws an NoResultException
            this.loggedUserBean.setLoggedUser(u);            
        }
        catch(NoResultException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       return "index";
    }

    /**
     * @return the login
     */
    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    /**
     * @param login the login to set
     */
    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    /**
     * @return the password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     * @param password the password to set
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="gsitePU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>gsite_mysql</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(foreignKeys=true)"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I changed the jpa persistence from openJPA to eclipseLink. The problem resolved.